# ConnectionString : Keyword Not Supported

Tags: visual-studio

Glad if someone can help ...

```
Visual Studio : 2015,
Data Connection Properties,
Identity Name : PropApp,
Connection String : Data Source= TOH-PC; Initial Catalog=PropApp; Integrated Security=True,
State: Open,
Type : Microsoft SQL Server (SQL Server Authentication),
Version : 13.00.4199,
Case Sensitive: False,
Owner : TOH-PC\TOH
```

ERROR ENCOUNTERED :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load()
con.connectionstring="TOH-PC; Initial Catalog=PropApp; Integrated Security=True"

System.ArgumentException occurred
Additional Information: Keyword not supported : 'toh-pc; initial catalog'.
```

Thank you for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved... 
Include "Server" in the connectionstring.

Private Sub Form1_Load()
    con.connectionstring="Server=TOH-PC; Initial Catalog=PropApp; Integrated Security=True"